# How to create PHP generated tooltips for ImageMapster?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, imagemapster

I'm working on a floor map for my company, to see where each employee has its desk, so if you wish to visit someone, you can easily find him beforehand.

I have created a `<map>` with a lot of `<area>`s and now I'm using [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster) to highligth a table and to display some information about an employee (photo, name, position etc. (small business card)) in a tooltip.

And because it is really not optimal to manually change `areas` in mapster initialization, I want to load captions of tooltips by PHP.

I've made this so far:

```
<div class="mapster-map">
    <img src="images/floor_2.png" border="0" width="1300" height="1300" usemap="map_floor_2" alt="" />
    <map name="map_floor_2" id="ImageMap-map_floor_2">
        <?php
            $found = array();
            foreach ($tables as $t) {
                $user = $map->getSeatedEmployee($t['id']);
                if (!empty($user)) {
                    $found[] = array('key'=>$t['id'], 'toolTip'=>$user['jmeno'] . ' ' . $user['prijmeni']);
                }
                echo '<area id="' . $t['id'] . '" coords="' . $t['coords'] . '" shape="' . $t['shape'] . '" alt=""
                title="' . (!empty($user) ? $user['name'] . ' ' . $user['surname'] : '') . '" href="' . (!empty($user) ? 'user_detail.php?id=' . $user['id'] : '#') . '" />';
            }
            $found = json_encode($found);
        ?>
    </map>
</div>
<script>
    $('img[usemap]').mapster({
        mapKey: 'id',
        fillColor: 'EE1C23',
        fillOpacity: 0.65,
        showToolTip: true,
        areas:[<?php echo $found ?>]
    });
</script>
```

So the outup `<area>`'s looks like this

```
<area id="2-13-2" href="user_detail.php?id=1" title="Adam Jones" alt="" shape="rect" coords="274,269,356,337">
<area id="2-13-4" href="user_detail.php?id=2" title="Bon Jovi" alt="" shape="rect" coords="189,269,271,337">
<area id="2-13-6" href="user_detail.php?id=3" title="Charles Copperfield" alt="" shape="rect" coords="104,269,186,337">
<area id="2-13-8" href="#" title="" alt="" shape="rect" coords="013,269,081,353">
<area id="2-13-1" href="user_detail.php?id=4" title="Christina Davis" alt="" shape="rect" coords="274,390,356,458">
```

But tooltips are not displaying, and in console there is no error. In firebug the `<script>` looks like this:

```
$('img[usemap]').mapster({
    mapKey: 'id',
    fillColor: 'EE1C23',
    fillOpacity: 0.65,
    showToolTip: true,
    areas:[[{"key":"2-13-2","toolTip":"Adam Jones"},{"key":"2-13-1","toolTip":"Bon Jovi"},{"key":"2-13-1","toolTip":"Charles Copperfield"},{"key":"2-13-1","toolTip":"Christina Davis"}]]
});
```

I'm hopelessly stuck on this, hope someone has an idea how to make this work.

Comment: Does this work in plain HTML, non-generated by PHP? I'm not sure about this, but should `areas` have two brackets? `areas:[[...]]`?

Comment: OMG, thanks! I did not notice this, of course there must be only one pair of brackets. Now it's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JavaScript `areas` should only have single brackets `areas:[...]` other than two nested ones `areas:[[...]]`. According to the documentation [here](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?docs.html#areas). So we just need to get rid of those extra brackets:

```
$('img[usemap]').mapster({
    ... ,
    areas:[{"key":"2-13-2","toolTip":"Adam Jones"},{"key":"2-13-1","toolTip":"Bon Jovi"},{"key":"2-13-1","toolTip":"Charles Copperfield"},{"key":"2-13-1","toolTip":"Christina Davis"}]
});
```

We can do this by removing them in the JavaScript here:

```
areas:[<?php echo $found ?>]
```

To

```
areas: <?php echo $found ?>
```

Since `$found` is an array, it has the brackets needed.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing but use jQuery variables, but its not working.. Any thoughts? jQuery('#locations-map').mapster({
        fillColor: 'efc254',
        fillOpacity: 1,
  stroke: true,
  strokeColor: '03325e',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  singleSelect: true,
  mapKey: 'state',
  boundList: jQuery('#boundList').find('li'),
  listKey: 'state',
        listSelectedClass: 'selected',
  showToolTip: true,
  
  areas: [ 'areasContainer' ]
    });